# MemcacheD on windows 7 home basic 64bits + xampp + Apache 2.4.2 + PHP 5.4.4

Tags: php, windows, apache, memcached, 64-bit

I looked for the entire internet and I didnt find the correct .dll for Memcached module.

I find some 'Memcached.exe' files, but I'm not sure if this module come with an executable file or it's a virus. I looked like a week and didn't find something could help me with this 'figth'!

Here is some tech especification of my computer's apache configuration
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

Somebody know where can I find it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to run Couchbase Server. Couchbase contains a bucket type for a memcached bucket with is exactly the same as running normal memcached (same code base) and it runs on Windows. You can download Couchbase here http://www.couchbase.com/download.